# JPA Criteria Query API for Select New

Tags: sql, jpa, criteria, criteria-api

I have to construct a Criteria Query for a use case where the output would be like..

select new WrapperXXXYYY(XXX.something, YYY.something) from XXX x, YYY y, where x.id = y.createdBy and ...

The Code that I created is..and the domain class here is Just a wrapper of other two Entity classes.

```
    CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<? extends T>  criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(domainClass);

    Root<JPAUser> user = criteriaQuery.from(JPAUser.class);
    Root<JPAReport> report = criteriaQuery.from(JPAReport.class);
    criteriaQuery.multiselect(builder.construct(domainClass, user.get("surrogateId"), report.get("projectId")));
    return  em.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
```

I'm getting the below Exception 
"javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: new near line 1, column 62  "

and the generated query is - 
[select new com.collabnet.ctf.server.report.jpa.JPAReportList(new com.collabnet.ctf.server.report.jpa.JPAReportList(generatedAlias0.surrogateId, generatedAlias1.projectId)) from com.collabnet.ctf.server.user.jpa.JPAUser as generatedAlias0, com.collabnet.ctf.server.report.jpa.JPAReport as generatedAlias1]

I see there a two "new" statements for domainClass, what is going wrong with the syntax?

Answer (score 8):

You can achieve constructor expression with Criteria in one of two ways:

```
criteriaQuery.select(builder.construct(domainClass, user.get("surrogateId"), report.get("projectId")));
```

or

```
criteriaQuery.multiselect(user.get("surrogateId"), report.get("projectId"));
```

Use `construct()` with `select()` or  use `multiselect()` **without** `construct()` .
You have mixed the two approaches and end up with nested constructor expression.